# Will a specific denormalization increase performance in a specific scenario?

Tags: database-design, optimization, database-recommendation, table, denormalization

Suppose I have a table with fields | a | b | c | d | ... | z | which contains millions of records and which will serve millions of queries a day. And the field `z` holds the `id` of some parameter which can be one of the five possible values. This parameter will **never** get new values.

What I need is the maximum possible speed and performance of `select` from this table. All other query types performance does not matter. Disk space doesn't matter much too.

Very important point is that in each `select` query I will **always** specify the value of `z` to **only one** value ( e. g. `where z = 1` ) Also ib the `select` query I will always filter record by other fields and also I will make some joins.

The question is: will it boost the performance of `select` to split the table into five tables each corresponding to one of the five possible values of `z`? I am going to use MySQL database but I would like to hear the general answer if one exists.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is: will it boost the performance of select to split the
>   table into five tables each corresponding to one of the five possible
>   values of z?

Yes, you could use partitioning here. Partition elimination will kick in. The partitioning will act as a leading index column.

Which brings me to the following point: Just add `z` as the leading column to all indexes. As you always filter on `z` (using an equality predicate) this will only help. (Except, if the index was unique anyway like an index on an `ID` column).

I'm generalizing a bit here like always with databases, but make sure to add filtering on `z` to your indexes.

Other techniques apply as well, of course, like making indexes covering.

I don't see the necessity for creating 5 tables, or using partitioning here. I can see how that might improve performance by a few percent, though, because `z` no longer needs to be stored.

If your app is generating enough load that a few percent of load matter, then your server is overloaded anyway by my definition. Still, it is worth a try if you don't care about increased development and maintenance costs.